# How to put alias column name of a query in another query while creating view

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT Address_1, Address_2,Address_3 ,Address_4,
    ISNULL(Address_1,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(Address_3,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(Address_2,'') + ISNULL(Address_4,'') AS Full_Address 
FROM landing_doctor_det
--------------------------------------

select clinic_institute_name,doctor_Name,Mobile_1,Address_1,category,City,specilisation,State,email_id
from landing_doctor_det where 
    clinic_institute_name is not null and doctor_Name is not null AND Mobile_1 is not null AND Address_1 is not null and
    category is not null AND City is not null AND 
    (specilisation is not null or State is not null or email_id is not null)
```

my main query is the second query. I want to add the column in the second query which i am getting after executing the first query(Full_Address)

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL; what RDBMS are you *really* using?

Comment: As for the problem, why can't you add that expression to your second query? What's stopping you..?

Comment: You've stated your intent but not actually asked a question - what is the problem you are having? Aside, it's *specialization*.

Comment: i am not understanding how to put it in view

Comment: @Larnu,@Stu in the first query i m getting the Full_Address column. Now I want to add the Full_address column in the Second select statement. and all those queries i want to put it in a view

Comment: @AbhishekBorse the word "view" appears in this question for the first time in your comment above. Please have a read through the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It seems you struggle to find a way to use "Full_Address" in your second query - correct? Your two queries select from the same table so the simple answer is to add that expression in the first query into the second. But perhaps the better path is to create a computed column for your table using that expression so you can freely refer to it in any query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply select all columns in one statement, like this:

```
SELECT 
  clinic_institute_name,
  doctor_Name,
  Mobile_1,
  Address_1,
  category,
  City,
  specilisation,
  State,
  email_id,
  Address_1, 
  Address_2,
  Address_3,
  Address_4,
  ISNULL(Address_1, '') 
    + ' ' + ISNULL(Address_3, '') 
    + ' ' + ISNULL(Address_2, '') 
    + ISNULL(Address_4,'') AS Full_Address
FROM landing_doctor_det
WHERE clinic_institute_name IS NOT NULLL 
  AND and doctor_Name IS NOT NULL 
  AND Mobile_1 IS NOT NULL 
  AND Address_1 IS NOT NULL
  AND category IS NOT NULL
  AND City IS NOT NULL 
  AND (
    specilisation IS NOT NULL 
    OR State IS NOT NULL 
    OR email_id IS NOT NULL
  )
```